# Use underscore.js "pluck" on a knockout observable array

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js, underscore.js

I have an observable array of objects and I want to pluck out the values using underscore.js

For example:

```
ko.observableArray([{
  id: ko.observable(1),
  name: ko.observable("name1")
},
{
  id: ko.observable(2),
  name: ko.observable("name2")
},
...])
```

And I just want to pluck the values inside of the object rather than the whole observable.

Can I do this with just one command?

I tried:

`_.pluck(myArray(), "id()")` and `_.pluck(myArray(), "id"())`

But these return an array of undefineds and "id is not a function" respectively.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Short answer

Use `_.invoke` instead of `_.pluck`

See [this sample fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jbustos/nvqroveg/).

### Long answer

`_.pluck(list, propertyName)` works as documented:

> A convenient version of what is perhaps the most common use-case for map: extracting a list of property values.

Or, as better exlained on lodash docs: `_.pluck(collection, path)`

> Gets the property value of path from all elements in collection.

So, if you do this:

```
_.pluck(myArray(), "id")
```

what you get is an array with all the `id`'s. And all of these `id`'s are observables, as in the objects of the original array

But you can use `_.invoke(list, methodName, *arguments)`, which, as documented:

> Calls the method named by methodName on each value in the list. Any extra arguments passed to invoke will be forwarded on to the method invocation.

or, on lodash version `_.invoke(collection, path, [args])`

> Invokes the method at path on each element in collection, returning an array of the results of each invoked method. Any additional arguments are provided to each invoked method. If methodName is a function it is invoked for, and this bound to, each element in collection.

In this way, you execute each observable, and get its value as expected:

```
_.invoke(myArray(), "id")
```

### Mind the viewmodels full of observables!

The first comment to this question has made me include this notice:

The best solution is using `ko.toJS` to convert all the observables in a view model into a regular JavaScript object, with regular properties. Once you do it, underscore, or any other library, will work as expected.

The `_.invoke` solution only works for a single level of observables, as this case. If there were several level of nested observables, it will completely fail, because it invokes a function at the end of the path, not at each step of the path, for example, `_.invoke` wouldn't work for this case:

```
var advices = [{
   person: ko.observable({
     name = ko.observable('John')
   }),
   advice: ko.observable('Beware of the observables!')
}];
```

In this case, you could only use `_.invoke` on the first level, like this:

```
var sentences = _.invoke(advices,'advice');
```

But this wouldn't work:

```
var names = _.invoke(advices,'person.name');
```

In this call, only `name` would be invoked, but `person` not, so this would fail, because `person` is an observable, thus it doesn't have a `name` property.

*NOTE: [lodash](https://lodash.com/) is another library similar, and mostly compatible with underscore, but better in some aspects*

Comment: `_.invoke` works but is not idiomatic - and it makes assumptions about the nature of the contents of the array at that. If `id` wasn't observable you'd have to change the entire call. If the entire `path` argument was a variable   where you could not predict whether it would refer to an observable or not, then using `invoke` would not work at all. @CaseyWebb's and @Mouhong Lin's solutions using `ko.toJS()` are better because they are idiomatic, immediately obvious to the reader and stable.

Comment: I fully agree with you. `ko.toJS` is the only way to convert a view model into a "normal" JavaScript object. Once that's done, you can use the underscore functions in a normal way. I do understand the implications of nested observables, which would make this fail. I'm updating my answer.

Comment: I like the explanation and the examples you provided so I picked this answer, but since you came to the same conclusion as another poster who answered first I was conflicted about which answer to choose. If this is incorrect let me know and I'll change that. I'm a longtime lurker, but new to asking questions. :)

Comment: Well, sometimes it's hard to choose what the best answer is. I can't help you with that. Simply try to think what answer would be the best for someone with the same problem, and choose it. Choose for the quality of the explanation and, if in doubt, the one which answered first. It's up to you. Rmemeber that the purpose of SO is to help people, so do what you think that can be more helpful for other people.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this by using the "map" function:

```
_.map(myArray(), function(item) {return item.id()});
```

But I was hoping to use pluck since it's the exact use-case for this type of scenario.

Comment: Please see my answer. What you were looking for was `_.invoke`

Answer (score 2):

Because `name` is a function, how about `pluck` your original array into an array of functions, then using `ko.toJS` to convert it into string array?

```
var myArray = ko.observableArray([{
    id: ko.observable(1),
    name: ko.observable("name1")
},
{
    id: ko.observable(2),
    name: ko.observable("name2")
}]);

var names = _.pluck(myArray(), 'name');
console.log(ko.toJS(names)); // Output: ["name1", "name2"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Unwrap it first

```
_.pluck(ko.toJS(myArray), 'id')

_(ko.toJS(myArray)).pluck('id)
```